# Is $\exists x\exists yP(x,y) \to\exists x\exists yP(y,x)$ valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

> Consider
>
> $$\exists x\exists yP(x,y) \to\exists x\exists yP(y,x).$$
>
> Is the above statement valid? Please explain why.

I thought is is valid and that I could write $\exists x\exists yP(y,x)$ as $\exists y\exists xP(x,y)$ and if  $\exists x\exists yP(x,y)$  is true then there must exist a $y$ for an $x$ too, and thus $\exists x\exists yP(y,x)$ is also true but the answer given is invalid.

Comment: Yes, it is......

Comment: Your argument is an intuitive semantic proof: from $\exists x \exists y Pxy$ we derive $Pab$ for two new terms $a$ and $b$ and then $\exists y Pyb$ followed by $\exists x \exists y Pyx$.

Comment: The answer given in what? This possibly sounds like an error in the source material but more information on where you found the question would help in being more certain.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Here is, for instance, a Gentzen-style proof.

$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{P(a,b)\vdash P(a,b)}{P(a,b)\vdash\exists yP(y,b)}\vdash\exists}{P(a,b)\vdash\exists x\exists yP(y,x)}\vdash\exists}{\exists yP(a,y)\vdash\exists x\exists yP(y,x)}\exists\vdash}{\exists x\exists yP(x,y)\vdash\exists x\exists yP(y,x)}\exists\vdash}{\vdash\exists x\exists yP(x,y)\rightarrow\exists x\exists yP(y,x)}\vdash\rightarrow.$

And here is a Hilbert-style one.

1. (Ax) $P(a,b)\rightarrow\exists yP(y,b);$
2. (Ax) $\exists yP(y,b)\rightarrow\exists x\exists yP(y,x);$
3. (1+2+Syllogism rule) $P(a,b)\rightarrow\exists x\exists yP(y,x);$
4. (3+$\exists$-rule) $\exists yP(a,y)\rightarrow\exists x\exists yP(y,x);$
5. (4+$\exists$-rule) $\exists x\exists yP(x,y)\rightarrow\exists x\exists yP(y,x).$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Suppose otherwise. Then

$$\exists x\exists yP(x,y)\tag{1}$$

is true while

$$\exists x\exists yP(y,x)\tag{2}$$

is false.

From $(1)$, we have some $a$ in the domain such that

$$\exists yP(a,y),\tag{3}$$

which, in turn, gives some $b$ in the domain such that

$$P(a,b).\tag{4}$$

Now $(2)$ being false means that, for any $c$ in the domain, we have  $\lnot\exists yP(y,c)$, so, letting $c=b$, we get

$$\lnot\exists yP(y,b).\tag{5}$$

But then $(5)$ is equivalent to saying that, for any $d$ in the domain, we have $\lnot P(d,b)$, so, letting $d=a$, we get

$$\lnot P(a,b).\tag{6}$$

But now $(4)$ contradicts $(6)$.

Hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. $\exists x\exists y P(x,y)$ means $P(a,b)$ for some $a$ and $b.$ This is an inference rule sometimes called existential instantiation. Then setting $y=a$ and $x=b$ we can infer $\exists y\exists xP(y,x)$ by existential generalization. Less formally, both of these sentences just say that the predicate $P$ is true for some input. The names of the variables used aren't relevant.